# Can someone clarify the definition of flux?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, physics, surfaces, vector-fields, surface-integrals

I am confused by the concept of flux as used in vector calculus. Suppose I have a sphere. On the inside of this sphere is a spherically symmetric electric charge distribution. Now I want to find the flux through the surface of the sphere.

Obviously, the electric field of that charge distribution is a vector field. So presumably I can apply a surface integral here to find the total flux through the surface.

But this is what I am having trouble understanding.  What am I adding up with a surface integral in computing the flux through a surface? In other words, I have heard flux described as "Field lines per unit area" of the surface. How can we quantify the density of a vector field? I thought in a vector space like $\Bbb{R}^3$ there would be an infinite number of possible lines going through a patch of a surface. In that sense, then this definition  of flux as "Field lines per unit area" makes no sense.

**My Question:**

Can someone clarify the definition of flux in a rigorous enough way that some of the mathematical contradictions (ie infinite number of lines through surface) I named are clarified?

EDIT:

Tom Apostol mentions the term "flux density vector field" that essentially assigns a flux density vector to each point in space. Perhaps answerers could clarify what this is as I think it's likely related to my question.

Comment: Flux is that thing that Doc Brown used to create his time traveling DeLorean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "infinite number of field lines through the surface" is to be understood in the sense that one field line goes through one surface element. We take the limit as the area of the surface element goes to zero and the corresponding limit of infinite field lines. This is of course heuristic.

Let us discuss flux in three dimensions.$^1$ Let $\Pi\subset\mathbb{R}^3$ be a parallelepiped and $S:=\partial\Pi$. Let $d\sigma$ be a measure-valued 1-form. We define the *outward flux* of the field $A$ as
$$F(\Pi)=\int_S \langle A,d\sigma\rangle$$
 Very laborious mathematics allows us to derive from this the general Stokes theorem in any dimension. See Arnold's book for a derivation using so-called *chains*.$^2$ In any case, the general definition of flux for a general manifold $M$ and $D\subset M,\partial D=:S$ is
$$F(D)=\int_S\langle A,d\sigma\rangle$$
where the inner product is now taken with respect to the possibly curved metric. Gauss' theorem is
$$\int_S\langle A,d\sigma\rangle=\int_D (\operatorname{div}A)\,dv$$ 
where $dv$ is the canonical measure on $M$. For the electric field we of course have $\operatorname{div}E=\rho$, so the flux is just the charge in $D$.

*Flux density* is simply the vector field $A$ used above.

---

$^1$ I am taking material from V.I. Arnold, *Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics* (1997) and Straumann, *General Relativity* (2013).

$^2$ Section 36. This book is an almost scarily complex discussion of classical mechanics. Definitely worthy of the label "Graduate Texts in Mathematics".

Comment: Regarding the point in your first paragraph, how exactly do we specify mathematically this "one field line to one surface element" property? Is that why you specify $d\sigma$ must be measure-valued?

Comment: @StanShunpike I specify that $d\sigma$ is measure valued because the integral can be understood in the Lebesgue sense. The "one field line" property is rather heuristic. The field lines are the integral curves of course. This property is just the statement that the integral curves don't intersect on the surface. The physical motivation is that we don't want to calculate the flux with a source/sink right on the surface.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how do you happen to know of all these books? You seem very familiar with many of them. Do you find them through google book search? local library? Personal library? I just know from personal experience buying books like these is expensive, so I am curious how you obtain access to them.

Comment: @StanShunpike I have bought some of them, others are available as PDFs online and others I get through my dad's Scribd account. I'm going to be raiding the library when I get to college, for all the books I can't get ahold of right now, because as you said, they *are* expensive.

Comment: Wow! Nice find! Arnold's book is great. Finally, someone who discusses Newtonian mechanics and the Galilean group in a crisp, serious way.

Comment: @StanShunpike I *think* Hall's *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians* is even more advanced with regards to its treatment of classical mechanics. However, that book is on my to-read list once I learn measure theory properly, so I can't say anything definitive. Arnold's book is the canonical reference for analytical mechanics, so it's not really *my* find.

Comment: I've heard of Hall, but I'll have to check it out more carefully. I think I ran across it while looking for QM books. What texts have you found useful in learning measure theory? I need to get better at that area.

Comment: @StanShunpike Don't ask me about measure theory! Yesterday I spent a good amount of time trying to decipher Lieb & Loss and Reed & Simon. I'm still not sure what I read. The physics chat was rife with me being confused and confusing others who thought they knew it.

Comment: lol I bet your version of being confused to anyone else would be clarity. Okay, what about statistical mechanics then? I'm reading QFT for the Gifted Amateur and they discuss the partition function. I looked up recommendations on Physics SE for books but the ones I found I didn't like.

Comment: @StanShunpike Haha, when I tried to understand the Lebesgue measure in $\mathbb{R}^n$, I decided with ACuriousMind that stuffing things with infinitesimal balls was rigorous enough -- despite the whole purpose of measure theory being that we shouldn't have to do that. Check out [Tong's statistical mechanics lectures](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/statphys.html).

Comment: @StanShunpike There was also something about beating dmckee with integral signs. Learning measure theory is not a pleasant undertaking.

Answer (score 1):

Flux can be thought of as the total "flow" of the vector field through some surface (when dealing with $\mathbb{R^3}$, it is 2-dimensional; in $\mathbb{R^n}$, it is an $n-1$-manifold). Consider, for example, the electric field generated by a positive point charge, $Q$, where the field lines are irrotational (with zero curl). We then have that $$\int_{|x|=R} \frac{\rho \vec{r}}{r^3}\cdot \widehat{\nu}\, dA = \int_{0}^{2\pi}\; \int_{0}^{\pi}\; \rho \cdot sin(\theta)\; d\theta\; d\phi = 4\pi Q,$$ where $\rho = Q\cdot \delta(x)$. The important thing here is that while there are infinitely many field lines going through a surface patch, each individual field line only goes through an infinitesimal part of the chosen surface.

Comment: what's $**$ here?

Comment: @900edges, hold over from legacy formatting on the site. Should be vector $\vec{r} = x \hat{x} + y \hat{y} + z \hat{z}$ and surface element $d\vec{S} = dA \hat{\nu}$ where $\hat{\nu}$ is the normal vector.